# How to install/config Git::Hooks to use with Gerrit

Tags: git, perl, hook, gerrit

The [Git::Hooks](https://github.com/gnustavo/Git-Hooks/wiki) is a Perl framework for implementing Git/Gerrit hooks. What is the procedure to install and config it to use with Gerrit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Installation

1) Install dependencies:

Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make libcrypt-ssleay-perl
```

Red Hat:

```
sudo yum install gcc make libcrypt-ssleay-perl
```

2) Install Git::Hooks:

```
sudo cpanm Git::Hooks
sudo cpanm Gerrit::REST
sudo cpanm JIRA::REST
```

### Configuration

0) Be sure you have the [hooks plugin](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-hooks.html) installed in Gerrit.

1) Create the Gerrit hooks patchset-created and draft-published (with execution permission) in GERRIT-SITE/hooks directory, with the following content:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Git::Hooks;
$ENV{HOME}="/home/GERRIT-USER";
run_hook($0, @ARGV);
```

2) Configure the Gerrit repositories:

Any repository can be set individually but it's easier to configure all-projects project in GERRIT-SITE/git/all-projects.git/config file like in the following example (some configurations itens can be added/removed as needed):

```
...
[githooks]
    plugin = CheckJira
    plugin = CheckLog
    plugin = CheckFile
    nocarp = 1
[githooks "gerrit"]
    url = https://GERRIT-SERVER
    username = GERRIT-USER
    password = GERRIT-PASS
    votes-to-approve = Verification+1
    votes-to-reject = Verification-1
    comment-ok = OK
    notify = OWNER
[githooks "checkjira"]
    jiraurl = https://JIRA-SERVER
    jirauser = JIRA-USER
    jirapass = JIRA-PASS
    matchlog = (?s)^(?:Revert\\s\")?\\s*\\[([^]]+)\\]
    status = In Progress
    status = Analysing
    status = Treating
    status = Evaluating
    status = Waiting Information
[githooks "checklog"]
    title-required = 1
    title-max-width = 60
    body-max-width = 80
[githooks "checkfile"]
    sizelimit = 5242880
    name = *.p[lm] /usr/local/bin/perlcritic --stern --verbose 5
    name = *.pp /usr/local/bin/puppet-lint --error-level error --with-context --with-filename
    name = *.sh LANG=en_US.UTF-8 /usr/bin/shellcheck --exclude=SC2046,SC2053,SC2086
    name = *.erb /usr/bin/erb -P -x -T - {} | ruby -c
...
```

And then include the all-projects config in all repositories by adding the folling at GERRIT-SITE/git/REPO.git/config

```
[include]
    path = GERRIT-SITE/git/all-projects.git/config
```

If needed any configuration can be changed/added at some specific repository changing the GERRIT-SITE/git/repo.git/config like in the following example (some configurations itens can be added/removed as needed):

```
...
[githooks]
    plugin = CheckWhitespace
[githooks "checkjira"]
    require = 0
    unresolved = 0
...
```

To learn more about Git::Hooks configuration options see [here](https://github.com/gnustavo/Git-Hooks/wiki#documentation).

3) Restart the Gerrit server

```
GERRIT-SITE/bin/gerrit.sh restart
```

Comment: In the above perl code, where are you verifying the policies? a sample patchset-created hook should help.

Comment: In the step 1 of the "Configuration" section you'll find the patchset-created hook, use that content as-is for the patchset-created AND draft-published hooks. I added more info in the [githooks "checkfile"] section... now the above configuration can check: the presence of JIRA tickets (CheckJira), the commit message (CheckLog), the max file size and the sintaxe of Perl / Puppet / Shell / Ruby files (CheckFile). More itens can be added.