# Enforce all new source code files checked in to have a particular comment

Tags: git, version-control, gerrit

Is there any possibility to enforce all new source code files checked in to a particular repository through Git to have a particular comment, else the push should fail with or without a message.
The source code will be of cpp or cxx or cc extensions.

[How do we verify commit messages for a push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524101/how-do-we-verify-commit-messages-for-a-push) is about enforcing something in the commit message but I want to enforce something in the source files that are being checked in.

Say for example, If I am writing a GPL library and anyone who commits into the repository should have the GPL license and author name, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to use Git::Hooks, a Perl framework for implementing Git/Gerrit hooks. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100437/how-to-install-config-githooks-to-use-with-gerrit) you have all info needed to install/configure it.