# How to configure server side hooks in Gerrit 2.16

Tags: git, gerrit, gerrit-trigger

I have started using Gerrit 2.16 as code review tool and want to configure server side hooks to validate the git commit message when a change is committed/pushed to gerrit.

Tried using hooks by copying scripts to $GIT_DIR/hooks (scripts like ref-update, patchset-created, change-merged), gave permission on the gerrit server but nothing works.

commit-msg hook can be enabled on local repository by using command give in gerrit UI

example:
git clone ssh://@:29418/Project1 && scp -p -P 29418 @:hooks/commit-msg /.git/hooks/

change_ID will be automatically generated if this hook is enabled.

This script commit-msg gets downloaded to local repository when above command is executed.
My question; can we find path of this script on the gerrit server, so that I can modify and enforce git commit message validation?

Or is there any other way to enable gerrit server side hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Executing hook from Gerrit_DIR "
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
GIT_DIR="/opt/gerrit/site/git"
PROJECT=$2
REFNAME=$4
UPLOADER=$6
OLDREV=$8
NEWREV="${10}"
BASE="<baseDir>"
RepoDir="$GIT_DIR/$PROJECT.git"
echo $RepoDir
echo $PROJECT
echo $8
echo ${10}


# execute the project specific hook
if [ -f "$RepoDir/hooks/commit-received" ]
    then
    echo "Executing the project specific hook"
    $RepoDir/hooks/commit-received $RepoDir ${10}
else
    echo "There is no project specific hook"
fi
```

Comment: not sure about the latest version of Gerrit, with 2.16 I was able to make this working: 
the above script is from  <GERRIT_DIR>/hooks/commit-received

Comment: nice solution, perhaps you could merge your answers into one post?

Answer (score 4):

No, you will not find the commit-msg path on the Gerrit server and Git/Gerrit will not use any hook you put on $GIT_DIR/hooks automatically. If you want to have local hooks you will need to manually install them in the REPOSITORY/.git/hooks local directory.

Gerrit does not run any of the standard git hooks in the repositories it works with, but it does have its own hook mechanism included via the [Hooks plugin](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/plugins%2Fhooks). See [here](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks/+/refs/heads/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/hooks.md) more info about the supported Gerrit hooks. The Hooks plugin is a [core plugin](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/config-plugins.html#core-plugins) (it's packaged within the Gerrit war file and can easily be installed during the Gerrit initialization).

I suggest you to take a look at the [Git::Hooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100437/how-to-install-config-githooks-to-use-with-gerrit) (a Perl framework for implementing Git/Gerrit hooks). We use at our company and it's really great. You can use it to implement what you want and a lot more...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira. To add further in Gerrit in gerrit 2.14 , the behavior of gerrit hook is changed as per below documentaion  https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.14.md#Behavior-change-in-ref_update-hook, commit-received is the file name that gets executed from the directory <GERRIT_SERVER>/hooks on the gerrit server,  when git commit is executed from git client. so commit-received can be a simple shellscript to validate the git commit messages.

Comment: Hello Marcelo Ávila de Oliveira, 
I have installed the GIT:Hooks from cpan, trying to find how can we implement gerrit server side plugin to validate commit messages 
in GERRIT_DIR  (/opt/gerrrit/gerrit_site):

Comment: cd /opt/gerrit/gerrit_site/git/Project_Example.git; cat config
[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = true
        bare = true
        logallrefupdates = true
[githooks]
    plugin = CheckLog
    nocarp = 1
[githooks "CheckLog"]
     title-required = 1
     title-max-width = 60
     body-max-width = 80
the gerrit trigger is still not invoked, when commit is executed, am I missing anything here ?

Comment: Have you created the "patchset-created" hook at "GERRIT-SITE/hooks" directory (Configuration step 1 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100437/how-to-install-config-githooks-to-use-with-gerrit)?

Comment: I am using Gerrit 2.16, For me only one hook is working, i.e commit-received. no other hook is working, below link also says same: https://www.gerritcodereview.com/releases/2.14.md#Behavior-change-in-ref_update-hook
Behavior change in ref-update hook
Instead of being invoked on every commit received, the ref-update hook is now invoked before the ref update operation is finalized. The previous behavior of the ref-update hook is moved into a new hook named commit-received.Sites using the ref-update hook should rename the hook file to commit-received.

Comment: this is working if I keep commit-received file in GERRIT_DIR/hooks, how do I create project specific hooks? example: GERRIT_DIR/git/project123.git/hooks/commit-received
what should be the content of file in GERRIT_DIR/hooks/commit_received file, so that it redirects the hook to a project specific hook

Comment: You can't do that on Gerrit. All hooks stay on GERRIT_DIR/hooks general directory, you create specific project configurations setting different GERRIT_DIR/git/project123.git/config files, as said in Configuration step 2 at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100437/how-to-install-config-githooks-to-use-with-gerrit.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Executing hook for patchset"
bold=$(tput bold)
normal=$(tput sgr0)
RED='\033[0;31m'
NC='\033[0m' # No Color
RepoDir=$1
NEWREV=$2
MSG=$(git --git-dir=$RepoDir log --format=%B -n 1 $NEWREV | awk -F"Change-Id:" '{print $1}')

Val=`echo $MSG | cut -c1-3`
if  [ $Val == "TR_" ] || [ $Val == "CR_" ] || [ $Val == "PU_" ]  || [ $Val == "FR_" ] || [ $Val == "CSR" ]
    then
    echo "The commit message is valid"
    exit 0

else    
    echo -e "The commit message ${RED}\"$MSG\"${NC} is not valid, please enter a valid commit message"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Place the above script in project speficic hooks directory 
GERRIT_DIR/git/<projectname.git>/hooks/commit-received.
This is working fine.