# Is there a way to get gerrit to reject commits without a JiRA ticket number?

Tags: gerrit

How does an admin configure Gerrit to automatically reject commits without JiRA ticket number? I've read this [documentation](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/cmd-hook-commit-msg.html) but not sure how to implement it on all branches **in a specific repository (not all repos!)**. Do all users need to download the file and copy it to their local repository or how does it work? What I want to achieve is that git/gerrit automatically rejects a commit that are missing a JiRA ticket number - doesn't have to be valid, it's up to the team to control that the ticket number is valid.

Answer (score 3):

The Jira plugin is based in the [ITS](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/its-base/+/master/src/main/resources/Documentation/config-common.md) plugin. These plugins have a association configuration that can be set to **MANDATORY**.

> MANDATORY : One or more issue-ids are required in the git commit message, otherwise the git push will be rejected.
>
> SUGGESTED : Whenever git commit message does not contain one or more issue-ids, a warning message is displayed as a suggestion on the client.
>
> OPTIONAL : Issues-ids are liked when found on git commit message, no warning are displayed otherwise.

The below config example is taken from the [Jira plugin](https://gerrit.googlesource.com/plugins/hooks-jira/+/fe6d51da2caba32fd63ffc558424f6c69790c44c/src/main/resources/Documentation/config.md) documentation.

```
[commentLink "Jira"]
    match = (\\[[A-Z][A-Z]+-[1-9][0-9]*\\])
    html = "<a href=\"http://myjira.com/browse/$1\">$1</a>"
    association = MANDATORY
```

Comment: @Antonow297296 the JIRA plugin can be disabled/enabled by project, hence it should cover your use case (i.e.: "in a specific repository (not all repos!)").

Answer (score 1):

The Git::Hooks is the best solution to this job.

See how to install and configure it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46100437/how-to-install-config-githooks-to-use-with-gerrit).

See more info about it [here](https://github.com/gnustavo/Git-Hooks/wiki#documentation).